# How to mock Linq Query with where predicate

Tags: c#, linq, mocking, moq

Below is the `listOfMeetings` of type meeting info.

It will return participant type.

How to mock below query with moq?

```
listOfMeetings.Where(x => x.MeetingURI == meeting.MeetingUrl)
    .FirstOrDefault().Participants;
```

Comment: Well it's hard to tell, usually mock involves a type that is mocked and passed to a constructor / property, I see only the usage, but no type definition, you need to put more code about what are you going to test.

Comment: `Participants` is likely an `IQueryable<Participant>`, so mock that interface?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to store test data and then setup the mock as an IQueriable, mapping it to the test data.

```
var meetingData = new List<MeetingInfo>();
//...populate the list with data

var mockList = new Mock<IMeetingList>();
mockList.As<IQueryable<MeetingInfo>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(meetingData.Provider);
mockList.As<IQueryable<MeetingInfo>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(meetingData.Expression);
mockList.As<IQueryable<MeetingInfo>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(meetingData.ElementType);
mockList.As<IQueryable<MeetingInfo>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => meetingData.GetEnumerator());
```

This will allow linq calls to the mock to be able to enumerate data for the test and apply predicates.